# warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character] in C++

Tags: c++

The little code I have compiles fine but when I go to run IntVector.cpp I get literally thousands of warnings like the following:

```
 IntVector:3:1533: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
  ...<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>
 IntVector:8:3: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+0008><U+0000><U+0000><E9><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>H<8D>E<D0>H...
 ?IntVector:9:2415: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
  ...<U+0000><U+0000><9E><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>|<U+0003><U+0000><U+0000>...
```

And so on. This is my first time trying to run a C++ program so I suppose the problem could be in my setup. I'm on Mac and using Emacs to code and compile and terminal to run it.

IntVector.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntVector.h"
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


  int* array = new int[0];
  int num_elements;
  int array_size;
  int expansion_factor;

void IntVector::expandArray(){

  }
void IntVector::add(int val){

    cout << "Hello"; 
  }
void IntVector::remove(int index){   
  }
int IntVector::get(int index) const{
    return index;
  }
void IntVector::removeLast(){
  }
void IntVector::set(int index, int val){
  }

std::string IntVector::toString()const {
    return "";
  }

IntVector::IntVector(int initial_size){

  }

IntVector:: ~IntVector(){}


int main(){

  IntVector v(5);
  v.add(5);

}
```

IntVector.h

```
#ifndef INTVECTOR_H_
#define INTVECTOR_H_

using std::cout;
class IntVector {
private:
  int* array;
  int num_elements;
  int array_size;
  int expansion_factor;
  void expandArray();
 public:
  void add(int val);
  void remove(int index);
  int get(int index) const;
  void removeLast();
  void set(int index, int val);
  std::string toString() const;
  IntVector(int initial_size);
  ~IntVector();


};
#endif
```

Comment: This `int* array = new int[0];` looks fishy. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @cigien Thanks for the response. I'm attempting to initialize the array there(I'm very new to C++ so good chance I did it wrong) but I commented out that line and received the same results.

Comment: @cigien — in this example it’s okay, since the zero-sized array is never used.

Comment: Did this code come from a website via cut-and-paste?

Comment: @PeteBecker True. Still fishy though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This warning means that you source code contains the null character. This is pretty much always wrong.

One potential cause for this may be that you are saving the file with a wide character encoding with your editor, but the compiler is expecting the input to have a narrow encoding.

Another typical cause for the warning is attempting to include or compile a binary file.

> cpp IntVector

It appears that you are trying to compile the file `IntVector` rather than the file  `IntVector.cpp`. Presumably, `IntVector` is a binary file.

Comment: I observe that the OP's warning appears to show longish sequences of null bytes, which does not seem consistent with a simple character-encoding mismatch.  An explanation that might fit the facts is that they are storing their source in a word-processing format instead of a plain text format.

Comment: @eerorika Thank you for your response. I'm just confused how this could be when I'm using Emacs both to edit and compile. And in my terminal I'm not doing anything special either, just "cpp IntVector" to run it.

Comment: @FruitManatee cpp? Shouldn't it be c++? Perhaps you saved fole as unicode with BOM, not all compilers support BOM